# removal the overlapping item in list by using 'while' in python 2.70

Tags: python-2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# 8-5 목록에서 중복 원소제거

def findUnique(list):
    k=len(list)
    for a in range(1, k-1):
        i=0
        while i<k:
            if list[i] == list[a]: 
                del list[a]        
            else:                  
                i=i+1

    return list
list = raw_input("목록 원소들을 입력하세요: ").split()
findUnique(list)
list = findUnique(list) 

print "갱신된 목록:", list
```

This is the program I have made. It did not work at all.
please tell me the solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the question?

Comment: ex) input list item: dog cat dog bird monkey dog bird , renewal list: dog cat bird monkey              like this

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the unique results from a list.

1. The hard way:

   ```
   strings=raw_input("Enter a line: ").split()
   def unique(listing):
       check={}
       result=[]
       for word in listing:
           check.setdefault(word,False)
           if check[word]==False:
               result.append(word)
               check[word]=True
       return result
    myresult=' '.join(unique(strings))
    print "The result is: %s"%(myresult)
   ```
2. The easy way

   ```
    strings=raw_input("Enter a line: ").split()
    def unique(listing):
              return list(set(listing))
    myresult=' '.join(unique(strings))
    print "The result is: %s"%(myresult)
   ```